# Key Error when migrating aldryn_bootstrap3

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3, migration, django-cms

I wan't to install aldryn_bootstrap3 Plugin in my local Django-Cms Environment. I'm using Django 1.8 and Python 2.7. 
I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-bootstrap3/wiki/0-Install-aldryn-bootstrap3) but without success. 
I previously installed [django-filer](https://django-filer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) which is necessary and added

```
'filer',
'mptt',
'polymorphic',
'easy_thumbnails',
```

to my INSTALLED_APPS. Then I installed aldryn_bootstrap3.

```
$pip install aldryn-bootstrap3
```

Added `'aldryn_bootstrap3'` also to my INSTALLED_APPS but when I want to migrate it i get following error:

> KeyError: u"Migration aldryn_bootstrap3.0001_initial dependencies
>   reference nonexistent parent node (u'filer',
>   u'0002_auto_20150606_2003')"

I'm new to django and dont't know what to do now. I looked into `env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/filer/migrations` directory and found a file called `0002_auto_20150606_2003.py` 
Any hints how I could solve this?

regards Manuel